# apache 2.2 to 2.4 upgrade, server limits seem to be being ignored

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I recently upgraded from apache 2.2 to 2.4 (as part of upgrading from Debian wheezy to debian jessie) I went from having plenty of free slots to handle demand surges to having virtually none. Apache seems to be ignoring my configuration settings.

According to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html a couple of options have been renamed but the old names should still work. I tried changing the names to the new ones but that made no difference. I also tried commenting out the "ifmodule" that was surrouding the directives but it made no difference.

I currently have in my apache2.conf

```
#<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    ServerLimit          24
    StartServers         10
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75.
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      64
    MaxRequestWorkers         1536
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
#</IfModule>
```

apache2ctl currently shows.

```
           Apache Server Status for localhost (via 127.0.0.1)

   Server Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_mirrorbrain/2.18.1

   Server MPM: worker

   Server Built: Nov 28 2015 14:05:48

     ----------------------------------------------------------------------

   Current Time: Thursday, 02-Jun-2016 16:35:50 UTC

   Restart Time: Thursday, 02-Jun-2016 16:16:11 UTC

   Parent Server Config. Generation: 1

   Parent Server MPM Generation: 0

   Server uptime: 19 minutes 38 seconds

   Server load: 1.76 1.46 1.84

       Total accesses: 120523 - Total Traffic: 15.5 GB

   CPU Usage: u29.85 s43.98 cu0 cs0 - 6.27% CPU load

   102 requests/sec - 13.5 MB/second - 134.7 kB/request

   104 requests currently being processed, 46 idle workers

 KWWKWWW___WKK___KW____KWW_WKWWWWKCWWKCW_WWWWW_KWWW_KWKWKWKK__KW_
 WWWWWWKWWKK_W__WKWC____WW_CKKW_W_KWK_WKW_____W_W_W_WWK_KWKWKWW_K
 W_W__K_KKW__WW_KCCK_WW

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
   "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

It seems Debian moved a block of server limit related settings out of apache2.conf and into mods-available/mpm_worker.conf . My system ended up with both and the settings in mpm_worker.conf were overriding my ones in apache2.conf.

Commenting out the settings in mpm_worker.conf fixed the issue.